# Getting error "Host is Unresolved: paras:80" while calling a web service in android through ksoap2

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I am new to android and trying to call a webservice in android through ksoap2 but dont't get success yet.When i am running this project, it is throwing "Host is Unresolved:paras:80" exception.Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Here is my java code:-

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloWebService extends Activity{

    String SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";
    String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";
    String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    String URL = "http://paras/Webservice/test.asmx";

    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hello);

        tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    //  tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);

        Hello();
    }

    public void Hello(){

    //  SoapObject results = null;
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        Log.d("request", request.toString());

    //  request.addProperty("Celsius", str);
    //  Log.d("request", request.toString());
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        Log.d("envelope", envelope.toString());
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        Log.d("envelope", envelope.toString());
        HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        Log.d("aht", aht.toString());
        try
        {
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject results = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
            Log.d("result", results.toString());
            tv1.setText(results.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            tv2.setText(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is missing the top-level domain (.com, .edu, .net, etc).